# adding new user in cakephp

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I am user Cakephp 2.3.8 
     I am get the problem to register new user my function in `Userscontroller.php` is

```
function registration() {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            if ($this->request->data['User']['password'] === $this->request->data['User']['confirmPassword']) {
                // echo "dfgf"; die;
                $this->request->data['User']['status'] = 1;
                $myPassword = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
                $this->request->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($myPassword, null, true);

                $repassword = $this->request->data['User']['confirmPassword'];
                $this->request->data['User']['confirmPassword'] = Security::hash($repassword, null, true);
            } else {

            }

            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->redirect('/');
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

when I save this value not save in table my model is

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(

        'username' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'on' => 'create', // here
                'last' => false,
                'message' => 'user name allready exist please choose another one'
            )
        ),
        'emailId' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'please enter an valid email'
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'on' => 'create', // here
                'last' => false,
                'message' => 'email allready exist please choose another one'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'match' => array(
                'rule' => array('match', 'confirmPassword'),
                'message' => 'Passwords doesnt match',
            ),
        ),

    );

    /**
     * match for form validation
     *
     * @
     * @return ture or flase
     */
    public function match($check, $with) {
        // Getting the keys of the parent field
        foreach ($check as $k => $v) {
            $$k = $v;
        }

        // Removing blank fields
        $check = trim($$k);
        $with = trim($this->data[$this->name][$with]);

        // If both arent empty we compare and return true or false
        if (!empty($check) && !empty($with)) {
            return $check == $with;
        }

        // Return false, some fields is empty
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem you are getting

Comment: just remove the validation of password and then try.

Comment: Try adding the line debug($this->User->validationErrors); right after you try to save.  That will tell you what's failing to validate.

Comment: thank you @anil Kumar right now its working fine (after remove validation of password)